# How to properly create a template string with conditions in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and have troubles translating my experience into it in certain things.
I have two string variables in some class. They can be null or have a word stored in them. I need to create a result string out of them which depends on if they have values or not like in the example:
Both variables have values: "string1 (string2)"
Only first variable has value: "string1"
Only second variable has value: "(string2)"
Both are null: ""

So far I came up with this, but I doubt, that this is how it is supposed to be. Seems very rough

```
var str1 = SomeClass?.Str1 + " " ?? string.Empty;
var str2 = "(" + SomeClass?.Str2 + ")" ?? string.Empty;
var result = $"{str1}{str2}";
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of template.  Seems you are trying to create JSON string? Also look into StringBuilder c#.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a JSON string. How is this a JSON? Just a regular string

Comment: Was looking at the fact you had braces in the string.  So was thinking your end goal might be Json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringBuilder` class to make the code more readable, an example:

```
using System.Text;

var sb = new StringBuilder();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SomeClass?.Str1))
{
    sb.Append($"{SomeClass.Str1} ");
}
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SomeClass?.Str2))
{
    sb.Append($"({SomeClass.Str2})");
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Please note that StringBuilder is more efficient than string concatenation in .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/string-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

non-null string + "null" will result in a non-null string.

```
"a" + null == "a" // evaluates to true
```

This means that `SomeClass?.Str1 + " "` and `"(" + SomeClass?.Str2 + ")"` will *never* be null.

Instead, do a null check on the member itself, without the surrounding text.

```
var result = "";

if (SomeClass?.Str1 is not null)
    result += SomeClass.Str1;
if (SomeClass?.Str2 is not null)
    result += " (" + SomeClass.Str1 + ")";
```

You can use StringBuilder as well, but the point of this post is to point out the fallacies with your null checks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using an extension method that does the job.  You can alter as required.

```
public static StringBuilder AddToString(this StringBuilder sb,string s)
{
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
sb.Append($"{s}");
return sb;
}
```

Usage

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AddToString("a").AddToString("").AddToString("c");
Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

//Result: ac //as there is a blank string.

Comment: dedicated method for such task is definitely an overkill

Comment: True but what if you needed to repeat for say 20+ props I would say its cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by Alik, I would recommend looking into StringBuilder.

You can do a lot of cool and advanced stuff like
.AppendFormat("Foo {0}{1}{3}", 'B', 'a', 'r').

For more info/features have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder